# Difficult regular expression for name validation

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I'm trying to write a regular expression to check whether or not a proposed name is valid in a gaming platform.

Rules:

- Name must contain at least 3 and no more than 20 letters
- Name must start with a uppercaseletter
- Name must never have two uppercase letters in a row
- Spaces are allowed, but must be preceded by a letter and be followed by an uppercase letter
- Hyphens are allowed, but must be preceded by a letter and be followed by a lowercase letter
- All uppercase letters must be followed by a lowercase letter unless they are followed by a space or hyphen

I know I can check separately for the length of the string so the first rule is irrelevant, but I figured I'd list it for good measure.

Test cases (Pass):

- Foo
- Hello World
- Hello-world
- Bigsby Platt-slatt

Test cases (Fail):

- foo
- Hello world
- Hello-World
- 33333333333

What regular expression can I use to solve this? Is it reasonable to expect to do this using only regular expressions, or will the pattern need to be analyzed using a different method?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code with your attempts?

Comment: You Not sure if you need to support Unicode, it will be a bit more difficult then.

Comment: Third pass-example does not pass rule 5.

Comment: @trincot edited rule 5, sorry..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a possible regular expression:

```
(?!.*[A-Z]{2})(?!.*[^A-Za-z][ -])(?!.* ([^A-Z]|$))(?!.*-([^a-z]|$))^[A-Z].{2,19}$
```

See demo on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/eG0dY7/1).

#### Explanation:

Several of the rules can be expressed as "cannot contain" kind of rules, and they are easy to implement with negative look-ahead (`(?! ... )`):

- No two capitals in sequence:

  ```
    (?!.*[A-Z]{2})
  ```
- No non-letter followed by either a space or hyphen:

  ```
    (?!.*[^A-Za-z][ -])
  ```
- No space that is followed by a non-capital or end of string (`$`):

  ```
    (?!.* ([^A-Z]|$)
  ```
- No hyphen followed by a non-lowercase or end of string:

  ```
    (?!.*-([^a-z]|$))
  ```
- Finally, the actual match is done with this: a capital followed by 2 - 19 characters:

  ```
    ^[A-Z].{2,19}$
  ```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is pretty much the bomb.